# Set selected images in the WordPress image uploader

Tags: javascript, wordpress, backbone.js

I'm using `wp.media` to select images in a plugin. The only problem is I don't know how to load the previously selected images.

```
uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
    title: 'Select images',
    button: {
        text: 'Select images'
    },
    multiple: true,
    selection: // current selection = images 173,174,175
});
```

Say someone previously selected 3 images, then they wish to add one more, this is what the frame should look like:

[image: image selection]

Answer (score 2):

I found an easy way to do it. It's not perfect, but it's simple.

```
// $input is a hidden input with attachmend IDs, comma-separated
var images = $input.val() || '-1';

uploader = wp.media.gallery.edit('[gallery ids="' + images + '"]');

uploader.state('gallery-edit').on('update', function(selection) {
  var images = [];

  selection.each(function(attachment) {
    images.push(attachment.toJSON().id);
  });

  $input.val(images.join(','));
});

uploader.open();
```

Comment: Saved my butt. The media manager has to be some of the most obfuscated code I've ever read through. Everything throws to some other level that's defined three files over :(